# UITextField-does not recognize touch events when tapping on the place holder text (iOS)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitextfield

If I use placeholder text inside a UITextField and tap on the placeholder text, it is not recognizing the touch events. How ever, in this same case, if I tap on the extreme left or the right sides outside the placeholder text of the same UItextField, it recognizes the touch events. The UItextField (with out a promt text) works perfectly as expected. Please advise.

Comment: You get UITextField touch event in textFieldShouldBeginEditing:

Comment: Have you set the UITextfield delegate? And Can you tell me how you set the placeholder means directly from xib or dynamically?

Comment: The delegate for the UITextField is set as the ViewController(implementing the UItextField delegate). All the UITextField events occur and it works perfectly as expected(if there is not place holder text in the text field). However, if I use any default place holder text in the UITextField, none of the events fire(when I tap on the textfield). However, the events fire and the keyboard appears when I tap on the extreme left and right corners of the same UItextField with a placeholder text

Comment: I check your issue in my project and its works fine for me. Have you added any code for UITextfield placeholder text or in delegate methods